# Is there a measure code that i can use to solve this?

Tags: powerbi, dax

My data set looks something like this
[image]

Its basically an attendance report. Now i want a pie chart in such a way that i can check how many candidates attended for 1-8 days, 8-15 days and 0 days. I need measure formulas for these 3 so that i can keep in value section of pie chart.

So far i tried this:

```
1-8 days = VAR DateRange =
CALCULATE(
    DATEDIFF(
        MIN('YourTable'[Date]),
        MAX('YourTable'[Date]),
        DAY
    ),
    'YourTable'[Attendance] = "Yes"
) VAR AttendeeCounts =
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('YourTable'[Unique ID]),
    'YourTable'[Attendance] = "Yes" &&
    DateRange >= 1 && DateRange <= 8
) RETURN
AttendeeCounts
```

But keeping this measure is just giving me a blank chart. I dont know why. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a measure when you need a calculated column. (You can't use a measure like an attribute, which can slice a "population" into segments.) If you create a calculated column, then you can do that.
I created this calculated column (not as a measure!) in the Students table:

```
Days Attended = COUNTROWS(
                FILTER(
                RELATEDTABLE('Attendance'),
              'Attendance'[Attended]=TRUE()
                ))
```

then I can create a calculated column to "bin" those:

```
Attendance Bin =   SWITCH(TRUE(),
        [Days Attended]=0,"Zero Days",
        AND([Days Attended]>=1,[Days Attended]<=7),"1 to 7 days",
        AND([Days Attended]>7,[Days Attended]<=15),"8 to 15 days",
        "lotsa days")
```

and then use that in my chart.

Comment: Buts lets say, i use a slicer to filter just a may data. in that case, i need only those people who attended for 1-8 days in May. By creating calculated column, The numbers will stay same right inspite of slicer selection?

Forgive me if this is a dumb question. I am new to power bi

Comment: What tables do you have in your model (related to just this part)? Do you have a separate Calendar table?

Comment: So, basically, I have a  list of unique IDs in column in one table power BI and i have list of Dates in a column in another table. Both the tables one column only. I did a cross join  to both the tables and now i have new table . in the co joined table i have added a new column in such a way that if the unique id is present on the given date, the value will be Yes or else it will be a No. The reference is from another table which captures the unique ID everytime a student swipes the ID card. But it does not have unique IDs  of students who are not present. Thats why i had to cojoin .